# Search appears to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Something appears to be wrong with search in chat and on main.

There's roughly 2 million posts containing "thanks" on Stack Overflow. [Search claims there's none](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks%22&mixed=0). The same on MSE - search yields no results regardless of what the search term is.

Chat is not doing specifically better - any searches there throws an error (the standardized "Something bad happened" - no details on my end).

Possibly related, while writing this question, no "similar questions" were loaded, and the related questions in the dropdown loaded forever.

What's going on here? It started happening recently, and it's reproduced by several people in SOCVR. I haven't tested more than SO and MSE for main site search, but all the chat sites throw errors when searching.

Comment: We're investigating.

Comment: The SOCVR deletionists strike again!

Comment: Search is broken.  Dog bites man.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Search should be back online now. We pushed a configuration change to ElasticSearch to enable [Search Slow Logging](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/index-modules-slowlog.html) and there was an issue with the change.

We rolled back the config change and will do further testing before pushing it again.